# how to set JDK in UBUNTU-20.04 using VSCODE?

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am having problem with vscode and jdk, I use it in windows with many configs, but with ubuntu, It brings me this error:
[image]

Everything is ok with `jdk-default` on vscode bash terminal.

jdk bin:

```
readlink -f $(which java) --> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

jdk version:

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

but, if I try to found a $JAVA_HOME on terminal, it returns empty.. I do not know more what can I do... already changed other thigns like:
configure.runtime:
[image]

[image]

json.conf:

[image]

If someone could help me with some link, documentations, or anything, thanks!

Comment: Did you install VSCode's Java Coding Pack?

Comment: yes, I have installed "java extension pack", and "spring boot extension pack" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **set JAVA_HOME** and **Add JAVA bin directory to the PATH variable** on local machine.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
echo $JAVA_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
echo $PATH
```

Once the above is finished, **restart** VS Code, below the `Java Tooling Runtime` tab, java extension should be able to detect the path automatically, then you can set `java.home` in VS Code successfully.

Don't forget to **reload window** to make the setting effective.

Answer (score 0):

List all available JVMs in your machine from the home directory as follows:

```java
$ cd ~
$ cd /usr/lib/jvm
/usr/lib/jvm$ ls

// Likely output
default-java java-11-openjdk-amd64  java-17-amazon-corretto
```

Choose what JDK you want to use. If it is amazon corretto, then the path to it would be:

```java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto
```

In the `settings.json` file, point the path to use amazon corretto:

```json
// settings.json
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto/"
```

Save changes, reload VS Code. You should be using Version 17 now.